# react-bootstrap-table set table columns total in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have implemented following example of react-bootstrap-table:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kr8ef2

I want to store the total in react state. How to set state?

Comment: You have the complete data with you. What is stopping you from calculating total and storing it to a state variable?

Comment: I was trying to store total in state from existing footerData variable so that there is no need to write extra function for total. It worked when I tried below solutions. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this example closer to the React way https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e53dgq?file=index.js

Comment: You are changing the state without using `setState` and it is not close to react way at all